# How to implement share action in android?

Tags: android

I want to implement share action in my project but when I used `MenuItem` it's giving Runtime error to use `MenuItemCompat` instead, but its too giving error.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_third_, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);


    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();

    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return true;
}

public Intent getDefaultShareIntent (){

   Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Extra Text");
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Comment: You should add the stacktrace as well.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have `subclassed` `AppCompatActivity` for your activity due to which you are getting this error, Kindly use following code

Initialize ShareActionProvider in your activity

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;


    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

        mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
        // Set share Intent.
        // Note: You can set the share Intent afterwords if you don't want to set it right now.
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }

    // Create and return the Share Intent
    private Intent createShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pk.nimgade.Bostan.Train.Schedule");
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share");
        return shareIntent;
    }
```

and this is how your xml view would be like

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share" />
```

please make sure your `SDK` is updated, In this peculiar case I did run into that, It is nasty when you don't know what is missing